# Input into an edit text not being captured for parsing

Tags: android, android-edittext

Im trying to capture a user input into an edittext flagged as a phone input type and Im unable to actually capture the number that's input for some reason.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PbfSampleApplication.this);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
EditText innerView = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.number);
String actualnum="tel:"+innerView.getText().toString();
```

Is what I'm working with. The main xml for the user input is

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:hint="Phone Number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

And what Im getting in the debugger is

```
v=android.widget.RelativeLayout{c1f5c25 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 
#7f0d00a2 app:id/activity_main}

innerView=android.widget.EditText{3bc4f87 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 
#7f0d00a7 app:id/number}

actualnum="tel:"
```

The issue is with actualnum. No matter what is input into the edit text Im actually not getting the userinput and I'm at a loss as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... By default there is no text inside the Edittext. So you will always get it as empty.

If you add a textwatchlistener, and print the text of edittext there, you will get the actual value of the edittext there.

PS: For your existing code to work as is, I would suggest you to add some default text in the XML, and that will be printed

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the text right after your activity is created, so your edittext string will always be empty. Use

```
String actualnum="tel:"+innerView.getText().toString();
```

In a button listener or something.